# Normalize Data in array of Objects (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

im trying to normalize some data sitting in an array of objects.

```js
[
  {id: 1, number: 10, x: 0.3, y: 0.4, …}
  {id: 2, number: 5, x: 0.5, y: 0.2, …}
  {...}
  {...}
  {...}
]
```

I want to map the x and y entry's on a new value between 0 - 1250. So I get the following Array of Objects

```js
[
  {id: 1, number: 10, x: 375, y: 500, …}
  {id: 2, number: 5, x: 625, y: 250, …}
  {...}
  {...}
  {...}
]
```

Whats the best Practice for that?

Best,
Chris

Comment: you can use .map method of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.map

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1, number: 10, x: 0.3, y: 0.4},
  {id: 2, number: 5, x: 0.5, y: 0.2}
];

// Use Array.map to iterate
const arr1 = arr.map(ob => {
  ob.x*=1250; 
  ob.y*=1250; 
  return ob;
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: The `.map` is mutating the objects, so it may as well be a `.forEach`

Comment: ^ If you do, you can also leave out the *return* statement.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this with `map` method.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1, number: 10, x: 0.3, y: 0.4},
  {id: 2, number: 5, x: 0.5, y: 0.2},
];


const res = arr.map(({x, y, ...rest}) => ({...rest, x: x * 1250, y: y * 1250 })); 

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `arr.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, {x: obj.x * 1250, y: obj.y * 1250}))` if you for some reason can't use the object rest spread syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `arr` is your array of object. You can use map which returns new modified array.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    id: 1, number: 10, x: 0.3, y: 0.4,
  },
  {
    id: 2, number: 5, x: 0.5, y: 0.2
  }
];

const normalize = (obj) => {
  x = obj.x * 1250;
  y = obj.y * 1250;
  return {...obj, x, y};
  // If you're only using mutating then
  // above lines can be
  // obj.x *= 1250;
  // obj.y *= 1250;
  // return obj;
}

// Not mutating array, output new array
const nonMutating = (arr) => {
  let newRes = [];
  arr.forEach(a => {
    newRes.push(normalize(a));
  });
  return newRes;
}

console.log(nonMutating(arr));

console.log("\n");

// Mutating input array
const mutating = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(a => normalize(a));
}

console.log(mutating(arr));
```